# Shiny Reactive renderUI and multiple dependent / coupled inputs

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, selectize.js, shinyjs

I have the following sample app and I need to be able to switch inputs for `multiple_choice_1_source` **OR**  `multiple_choice_2_type` without breaking the app and **hiding** `submit_request_button_ui` and `ColnamesInput` when the inputs from  change.  Basically, the user should be able to revise the inputs after clicking the "submit" button and the app should reset to its previous state.

What I have tried:

`shinyjs()` - this just hides and does not clear the inputs. This means that once I press the `submit_request_button` then any change made to `multiple_choice_2_type` is still processed and reacted upon. In the actual app, I have the submit tied to very large tables. I want to prevent the fetch for 
`selected_data()` from re-running and clear and hide the elements that were created in the first two choices.

`reactive` - I tried to make the observers listen to some reactive triggers that take dependencies from more than one input. I used `user_input_rv` to store the values etc but this fails as the observers are triggered more than once, so when I click the submit button, the if statements within the `reactive({})` are triggered twice, essentially downloading each dataset more than once. Also it fails.

`isolate` - I have not been able to make this work. I tried multiple combinations of isolate with no success.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(

   selectizeInput(inputId ='multiple_choice_1_source',
                  choices = c("db1","db2","db3","db4"), # like this because we want the selected to be blank on initialisation
                  label = "1. Select source",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  size = 10,
                  width = '100%'
   )

   ,uiOutput(outputId="multiple_choice_2_type_ui")
   ,uiOutput(outputId="submit_request_button_ui")
   ,uiOutput(outputId="ColnamesInput")
)


server <- function(input, output)
{

   user_input_rv =  reactiveValues(

      source_picked             = NULL,
      last_used_source          = NULL,

      type_picked               = NULL,
      series_picked             = NULL,
      last_used_series          = NULL,

      selected_data             = NULL,
      final_selection           = NULL
   )

   observeEvent(input$multiple_choice_1_source, {

      user_input_rv$source_picked <- input$multiple_choice_1_source

      #change data loaded under type picked.
      user_input_rv$type_picked <-
         if (        input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db1"){ paste0(colnames(mtcars))
         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db2"){ paste0(colnames(diamonds))
         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db3"){ NULL
         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db4"){ NULL
         }

      output$multiple_choice_2_type_ui <- renderUI({

         selectizeInput( inputId = 'multiple_choice_2_type',
                         choices = paste(user_input_rv$type_picked),
                         label= "2. Select type",
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         size = 10,
                         width = '100%',
                         options = list( placeholder = 'Type',
                                         maxItems =1
                         )
         )
      })

   }) #first observeEvent for source type and data load.

   observeEvent(input$multiple_choice_2_type,{

      output$submit_request_button_ui <- renderUI({

            actionButton(
               inputId = "submit_request_button",
               label = " Get data "
         )
      })
   })#second observeEvent for submit_request_button_ui

   observeEvent(input$submit_request_button, {

      selected_data <- reactive({

         if( input$multiple_choice_1_source =="db1"){

             mtcars


         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db1")                 {

         diamonds


         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db3")      { NULL

         } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db4"){ NULL
         }



      })

      user_input_rv$series_picked <- input$multiple_choice_2_type

      user_input_rv$selected_data <- selected_data()


            min_cols <- as.integer(1) # default 1
            max_cols <- as.integer(length(colnames(selected_data())))
            #print(max_cols)


            #this renderUI creates the right-hand side column of the app COLUMNS
            output$ColnamesInput <-  renderUI({

               lapply(min_cols:max_cols, function(z) {

                  column(width = 3,
                         offset = 0,
                            selectInput( inputId = paste0("cols","_",z),
                                         label = paste(input$multiple_choice_2_type,": ",colnames(selected_data())[z]),
                                         choices = unique(selected_data()[[z]]),
                                         multiple = TRUE
                            ) #selectizeInput

                  )

               })#lapply inner

            }) #renderUI for columns

   }) #third observeEvent for data selection and customisation

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `eventReactive`?

Comment: Yes, but I only tried replacing the reactive for `selected_data()`

Comment: If you want the values to only be changed when you press submit button, then why are you using `reactive expression` or `reactiveValues`?

Comment: Good question - summarizes how comfortable I am with shiny reactivity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a the code in which I have removed the `reactive expression` from and used a local variable `selected_data` instead.

```
  observeEvent(input$submit_request_button, {

    # selected_data <- reactive({

      # browser()
    selected_data <- NULL

      if( input$multiple_choice_1_source =="db1"){

        selected_data <- mtcars


      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db1")                 {

        selected_data <- diamonds


      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db3")      { selected_data <- NULL

      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db4"){selected_data <-   NULL
      }



    # })

    user_input_rv$series_picked <- isolate(input$multiple_choice_2_type)

    user_input_rv$selected_data <- selected_data


    min_cols <- as.integer(1) # default 1
    max_cols <- as.integer(length(colnames(selected_data)))
    #print(max_cols)


    #this renderUI creates the right-hand side column of the app COLUMNS
    output$ColnamesInput <-  renderUI({

      lapply(min_cols:max_cols, function(z) {

        column(width = 3,
               offset = 0,
               selectInput( inputId = paste0("cols","_",z),
                            label = paste(isolate(input$multiple_choice_2_type),": ",colnames(selected_data)[z]),
                            choices = unique(selected_data[[z]]),
                            multiple = TRUE
               ) #selectizeInput

        )

      })#lapply inner

    }) #renderUI for columns

  }) #third observeEvent for data selection and customisation
```

Now when you change the select input options the `ColnamesInput` do not get triggered. It gets triggered only after you click the submit button.

**[EDIT]:**

Might not be the best method, but I think I am able to achieve what you wanted. Also, I have taken the liberty on using the `reactiveValue` that was already defined in your server. Have a look at the modified server code below:

```
server <- function(input, output)
{
  user_input_rv =  reactiveValues(

    source_picked             = NULL,
    last_used_source          = NULL,

    type_picked               = NULL,
    series_picked             = NULL,
    last_used_series          = NULL,

    selected_data             = NULL,
    final_selection           = NULL
  )



  observeEvent(input$multiple_choice_1_source, {


    user_input_rv$source_picked <- input$multiple_choice_1_source

    ###Start: To check if the source changed#########
    if(!is.null(user_input_rv$last_used_source))
    {
      if(user_input_rv$last_used_source != user_input_rv$source_picked)
      {
        shinyjs::hide("ColnamesInput")
        user_input_rv$last_used_source = user_input_rv$source_picked
      }
    }else
    {
      user_input_rv$last_used_source = user_input_rv$source_picked
    }
    ###End: To check if the source changed#########


    #change data loaded under type picked.
    user_input_rv$type_picked <-
      if (        input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db1"){ paste0(colnames(mtcars))
      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db2"){ paste0(colnames(diamonds))
      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db3"){ NULL
      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db4"){ NULL
      }

    output$multiple_choice_2_type_ui <- renderUI({

      selectizeInput( inputId = 'multiple_choice_2_type',
                      choices = paste(user_input_rv$type_picked),
                      label= "2. Select type",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      size = 10,
                      width = '100%',
                      options = list( placeholder = 'Type',
                                      maxItems =1
                      )
      )
    })

  }) #first observeEvent for source type and data load.

  observeEvent(input$multiple_choice_2_type,{


    ###Start: To check if the series changed######### 
    user_input_rv$series_picked <- input$multiple_choice_2_type

    if(!is.null(user_input_rv$last_used_series))
    {
      if(user_input_rv$last_used_series != user_input_rv$series_picked)
      {
        shinyjs::hide("ColnamesInput")
        user_input_rv$last_used_series = user_input_rv$series_picked
      }
    }else
    {
      user_input_rv$last_used_series = user_input_rv$series_picked
    }
    ###End: To check if the series changed#########

    output$submit_request_button_ui <- renderUI({

      actionButton(
        inputId = "submit_request_button",
        label = " Get data "
      )
    })
  })#second observeEvent for submit_request_button_ui

  observeEvent(input$submit_request_button, {

    # selected_data <- reactive({

      # browser()
    shinyjs::show("ColnamesInput")
    selected_data <- NULL

      if( input$multiple_choice_1_source =="db1"){

        selected_data <- mtcars


      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db1")                 {

        selected_data <- diamonds


      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db3")      { selected_data <- NULL

      } else if ( input$multiple_choice_1_source == "db4"){selected_data <-   NULL
      }



    # })

    user_input_rv$series_picked <- isolate(input$multiple_choice_2_type)

    user_input_rv$selected_data <- selected_data


    min_cols <- as.integer(1) # default 1
    max_cols <- as.integer(length(colnames(selected_data)))
    #print(max_cols)


    #this renderUI creates the right-hand side column of the app COLUMNS
    output$ColnamesInput <-  renderUI({

      lapply(min_cols:max_cols, function(z) {

        column(width = 3,
               offset = 0,
               selectInput( inputId = paste0("cols","_",z),
                            label = paste(isolate(input$multiple_choice_2_type),": ",colnames(selected_data)[z]),
                            choices = unique(selected_data[[z]]),
                            multiple = TRUE
               ) #selectizeInput

        )

      })#lapply inner

    }) #renderUI for columns

  }) #third observeEvent for data selection and customisation

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @SBista . The problem is that `ColnamesInput` remains visible when the choices for the two `selectizes` change. I need to hide them.

Comment: @J.Doe., I have edited the code to achieve what you wanted. Have a look. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @SBista . It gets the job done. I think it's as efficient as it can be made to be. I was on the right track with those `reactiveValues` at the top but I had failed more than once. Where you got it 100% right was the nested if statement. Thank you again!